# Changeset scheduled for retry

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Migration finishes and 1 failure messages appears. I click the link "retry" and a dialog shows:

> Changeset 8360 scheduled for retry.

When will it retry?

Where can I see retries?

The message says about a changeset of a file but the whole project wasn't migrated. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can check on why the changeset failed by clicking on view details link on the Migration Failures page

Once the underlying root cause of the failure is resolve, please click on retry link to retry the failed changeset